# Load PDF with Eye Catching Effect

Tags: browser, pdf

I have developed a winforms app. that lets the users click on a file name
and then it loads it in the browser as a PDF. When the user clicks, it
refreshes the page as usual, but it is not very pleasant on the eyes.

**Note:** it is chrome based browser

I am looking for suggestions on how to put a nice smooth loading effect to replace the current loading effect. Following is the screen recording of the current effect:

[image: Screen Recording]

Comment: Quickly fade that part of the screen out, load the PDF, load it back in. It's Lorem ipsum btw.

Comment: So like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497826/better-algorithm-to-fade-a-winform or https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/b5fe06b9-04e0-499e-93ac-a31b6a87e546/opacity-fading-screens?forum=winformsdesigner but for the PdfViewer

Comment: @Gantendo sorry I didnt get your point, how can I fade the part of screen? 'Lorem ipsum' is just to use a sample, since its assignments data, so I had to put sample text.

Comment: @Gantendo that seems good starting point, I will play with that, thank you

Comment: Good luck, let us know if it worked out. You wrote *Lore* ipsum in the .gif; it is just a typo ;-)

Comment: I tried it, but it is bound not to resolve my issue, simply because the issue is exactly at the time when the browser loads the PDF, when i tried your solution (thanks to other SO posts), it did added the effect but the main effect as in my GIF, is not eliminated, it only adds the transition afterwards, I am now trying to load my own HTML into browser, hoping to load the page content with my own CSS and/or JS, lets see how that goes